# Is this sentence using Subjunctive Mood?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

Here is the sentence I'm confused about:

> If I have not seen as far as others, it is because giants were
>   standing on my shoulders.
>
> (Hal Abelson, MIT Professor)

My difficulty is to understand the verb *were*. I know we can't use *are* because that is not the truth. However, why *were*?

Comment: It's not subjunctive, it's past tense. We can't use *are* because we're talking about the past.

Comment: Think simple. It's just the past tense as Peter Shor points out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your verb is *stand*. The auxiliary verb is *to be*. The present tense of your verb phrase is: "are standing".

*Were standing* is called the **past progressive** tense. It is describing an on-going activity in the past that ended before the present moment.

It is also a play on a famous sentence written by Isaac Newton, who credited the work of others before him, as one who discovers by building on previous discoveries:

> "If I have seen further, it is by standing on the shoulders of giants."

The first person to have actually written these words was Bernard of Chartres in 1159. It was probably inspired by Greek mythology, where the blind giant Orion carried his smaller servant Cedalion on his shoulders to provide himself with 'vision'.

Comment: Thank you. So the quote is just a sentence that describes something happened before, right?

Comment: @AppalachianMath - yes, it already happened.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Peter Shor, here are examples.

> Tut SASCO members were on strike.

Past-tense statement.

> Tut SASCO members are on strike.

Present-tense statement.